# Automatically split y-axis on Highcharts if series' values are not similar

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a page that allows people to select values to graph from a set of values and sometimes those will be very different, e.g. 1-10 for series A and 1000-1200 in series B.

Right now, that would make series A very difficult to read, but this could be solved by putting it in a different y-axis.

Has anyone done this with Highcharts before / know of a nice way to handle it?

I thought I had seen a plugin for this before (that I can't find now).

The alternative will be to find the minimum and maximum for each line and split them up manually.

Comment: How are you currently doing it? This can be fixed, but it would be good to see your current implementation. Especially how you handle showing the different series when the users selects a value.

Answer (score 0):

How about using just two separate yAxes? Just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/p8f8ko6z/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: [{
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    }],
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis

    }, { // Secondary yAxis
        opposite: true
    }],
    series: [{
        yAxis: 1,
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

    }, {
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }]
});
```

So no matter what data you have, always use two separate axes. You can add specific color and title to show which series is connected to which axis.

Comment: That works well when your data is static, but I could have 50 series, some that should share an axis and some that shouldn't.

Comment: Just before adding series check extremes, if are similar to axtucla axis (getExtremes() method) then add to that yAxis. If not, add axis, then add series.

Comment: Right - that's what I was asking for built in.  I'll do that myself though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the series options when you build the chart you can specify a secondary yaxis:

```
Series: {
  yAxis: 1
}
```

[series.area.yAxis](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.area.yAxis)

You can also separate the yAxis from each other:

[Two panes, candlestick and volume](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume)